# NSMutableURLRequest time out interval

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest

I have 2 separate NSOperationQueues where two different web service operations are handled in parallel. For both web services the time out interval is set to 120 seconds(2 minutes). Both the web services are getting timed out during slow internet connection but not at the specified interval of 120 seconds.

WebService1 in operationqueue1 gets started at 10:27:29(hh:mm:ss) and getting timed out at 10:29:51, which is 142 seconds.

WebService2 in operationqueue2 gets started at the same time, i.e., 10:27:29(hh:mm:ss) and getting timed out at 10:30:53, which is 205 seconds.

Both are expected to get timed out at the same interval of 120 seconds but that is not happening.

Whenever time out interval is set for NSMutableURLRequest, there is some time delay in the time out. Why this is happening and how this could be handled. 
Please help me here.

Comment: It's likely that the operationqueue's are operating on an async thread, which means the OS might not be running that thread every second. Is there a specific reason you need the timeout to be exactly at 120 seconds?

Comment: Just because the user is not wanted to wait for a quite long time. SO is there a way to handle such thing?

Comment: 120 timeout? I hope you have specific reasons for that, 30 sec are enough for a mobile app.

Comment: yes there are reasons for that. the app is actually used with mobile network and not with wifi and in most of the cases this is being used in slow network connection areas, also the data being downloaded is huge enough.

Comment: So can anyone please let me know what is the way to handle proper time out for two parallel web services that are asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

There are different discussions on Apple Dev Forum and stack overflow about custom time out interval not respected, I think that they solved in latest iOSs release.
I can suggest you only to create your own timer and cancel the connection after that interval.
Check this discussion on [Apple forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/108087#108087)

Answer (score 0):

You can set time out interval while creating the request as below -

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];
[myRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[myRequest setHTTPBody:myData];

NSURLConnection *myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Alternatively, you can set the time like below statement as well -

```
[request setTimeOutSeconds:1000];
```

Comment: Setting time out is not the issue, the behaviour of time out is the issue.